# Check Message If read and unread

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

i wants update based on id_ .in front end level this id did't get..how to pass this id to conroller..And same thing If i read the inbox message i wants to change inbox font style .

Comment: What is rcp_id_in ? A column?

Answer (score 2):

read message inbox:

```
   1. Add new field in inbox message table named `is_read` type `int`.

   2. And write a select query to select is_read and check whether it is 0 or 1.

   3. If 'is_read' = 0 write a CSS style and if 'is_read' = 1 write a different CSS style for the font.

   4. And you can fix your self 0 as unread and 1 as read.

   5. Then write a update query for 'is_read' as 1 , When selecting the inbox message.
```